# IE 11 WooCommerce, jQuery issue

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

When I attempt to add a product to my basket in WooCommerce I get the following error in the console:-

> Object doesn't support property or method 'block'

This following line of code is highlighted with this error:-

```
a(".shop_table.cart, .updating, .cart_totals").fadeTo("400","0.6").block({
    message: null,
    overlayCSS: {
        opacity: .6
    }
})
```

The above code is from the minified version.

An unminified version can be found at:-

[add-to-cart.js](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart.js#L84)

Product information:-

- WordPress V 4.7.2
- WooCommerce V 2.6.13
- jQuery V 1.12.4
- IE V 11.0.9600.17843

Has anybody had this issue before?

Does anybody know of a resolution to this issue?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, even a push in the right direction.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I assume `a` is a reference to jQuery? If so `block()` isn't a standard method. If it's part of another library then you need to include it in the page

Comment: This code is in the add-to-cart.min.js, the core woocommerce plugin files. https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart.js line 84

Comment: Did you try to use full file version of add-to-cart.js ?